# SUM gives me a date instead of a number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I am writing a few simple formulas for Google Sheets and I've been stuck on this for a little while now. I am trying to get a quick overlook of how many people got added to a sheet in the past week, counting from Saturday, but unfortunately, it's not working.
I have this piece of code to set the date since last Saturday.

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())
```

This works just fine. The output gives the date as 3/7/2020.

I then have a different row which checks if the recruitment date, which is stated somewhere differently, is bigger or equal to past Saturday. It checks it like this:

```
=IF(I2>=K2, "1", "0")
```

This gives an output of either 1 or 0 (1 if it was on Saturday or after Saturday, 0 if not).

Then I went to the main page, where I want to put the SUM. I put the following code:

```
=SUM('Control Center'!J2:J)
```

It should just add the 1's that are said earlier, but instead, it gives me the following date: 12/30/1899.

Does anybody know what went wrong? If you need any clarification, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

go to **123** menu and select **Automatic** or **Number**:

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotation marks off the 1 and 0 so:

=IF(I2>=K2, 1, 0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the SUM function. The PROBLEM is that the cell is formatted to receive a date.

**So, if you put a 1 in a cell that is formatted to receive a date it will be converted to some date, like 01/01/1900.**

TO FIX:

1. Select the cells that are wrong
2. go to Format > 123 Number
3. Select automatic, or what ever format you want for the cell(s)

SCREENSHOT EXAMPLE:

[image: Screenshot of example problem]

[image: Screenshot of step 3]

[image: Screenshot of problem fixed]